# Where do the parameters come from when sending a post request in ZPL?

Tags: ruby, zebra-printers, zpl

I'm also trying to code this in Ruby. So an example in ruby would be splendid!

Comment: Can you provide some more detail?  Are you using a ZebraLink SDK?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure which parameters you were looking for, the ZPL, the HTTP parameters, etc.  To print something like a directory listing in ZPL using HTTP POST to a Zebra printer, it should have the format:
POST /pstprnt HTTP/1.1`<CR><LF>`Content-Length: 9`<CR><LF><CR><LF>`^XA^WD^XZ

I don't have a ruby example, but in javascript it looks like this:

```
function print_this(zpl, ip_addr)
{
  var output = document.getElementById("output");
  var url = "http://"+ip_addr+"/pstprnt HTTP/1.1";
  var method = "POST";
  var async = true;
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  request.onload = function () {
    var status = request.status; // HTTP response status, e.g., 200 for "200 OK"
    var data = request.responseText; // Returned data, e.g., an HTML document.
    output.innerHTML = "Status: " + status + "<br>" + data;
  }

  request.open(method, url, async);
  request.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", zpl.length);

  // Actually sends the request to the server.
  request.send(zpl);
}
```